# Is there a way to vectorize, element wise logic, when the logic depends on prior values?

Tags: loops, if-statement, conditional-statements, vectorization

Wonder if there's even a way to vectorize this... Let's say I have the following arrays of the same length, A, B, C.  I have in pseudocode:

```
> for i in range(2, length(A)):
>     if (A(i) > B(i)) && (C(i) > C(i - 1)):
>        C(i) = 1
>     else:
>        C(i) = 0
```

Here I'm using the previous value of C in my logic, but the values of C depend on the logic itself.  Is there a way to re-write this so it is vectorized?  So I'm comparing entire vectors, as opposed to doing for loops?  If not, is there a way to do a two part calculation, so that the maybe only part of it is element wise, and the rest is vectorized?  **I have a huge if statement with a lot of conditions (40+ conditions) - and am trying to simplify it but can't think of a way due to the fact that it depends on yesterday's value...**

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "vectorize"? a) Implement this using SIMD instructions (if so, what target architecture?), or b) Write this without a loop in a language like matlab/python/... (if so, which one?)

Comment: I would prefer to just have something like  A > B & C > Ct  or something.  Comparing entire vectors to each other as opposed to each element within each vector with each other

Comment: Ok, another question, Is `C(i)` before it gets a new value only either 1 or 0 (essentially a boolean) or can it be an arbitrary integer/real?